# React Native Properties can be only defined on Objects

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm trying to setup navigation in my react-native app using react-navigation.

I have tried using navigation from other packages like react-native-router and react-router. I have looked at other answers on stackoverflow but none of them seem to answer my question. Here is the libraries and their versions that I am using

```
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "^0.60.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.0"
    "node": "12.9.1",
    "npm":"6.11.2"
```

Here is my code for app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';

import ColorList from './components/ColorList'

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: ColorList},
});

const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

export default App;
```

Expected result:

I want to be able to create a stack navigation

Actual result: 
Shows an error that "Properties can only be defined on Objects" an then after about 2 seconds, the screen goes blank and stays that way.

It also shows other errors (createstackNavigator has been moved to react-navigation-stack) from time to time without me doing anything to the code (except only reloading) and then that also vanishes and the screen goes blank again.

I am using my galaxy Note 9 for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

From [react-navigation 4.0 release notes](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/releases):

> We've extracted out the navigators to separate repos in this version. Please refer to the individual packages for installation instructions.

```
createStackNavigator - react-navigation-stack
createDrawerNavigator - react-navigation-drawer
createBottomTabNavigator, createMaterialTopTabNavigator - react-navigation-tabs
```

So, if you need to use StackNavigator, you have to install it and import as a separate package.

Here is the [documentation for StackNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues So what worked for me was dowgrading the package. Try this version and It should work:

`"react-navigation": "^3.11.0"`